# Automatic power off circuit for battery charger

Tags: relay, battery-charging

I'd like to ask you a question about my circuit to automatically turn off battery charger. It works now fine except when voltage is close to the switch of treshold, coil of relay sounds noisy so I know that I need some histeresis but have now idea how to implement it there.

Thank you[image: ![Circuit]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIzP9.png)

Comment: R6 value is 10kOhm and D1 is 5V1 Zener

Comment: Is this for educational purposes? Otherwise you would be better off buying an IC that does the job for you.

Comment: absolutely just for amateur needs

Comment: Try a feedback resistor from LM358 output pin to non-inverting input - try 100 kohm initially - if too much hysteresis then try a higher value.

Answer (score 1):

Hystersis is positive feedback. You  may know you can get negative feedback by connecting the amplifier output with a resistor to the inverting input. So you can get positive feedback by connecting a resistor to the positive input. Sometimes a small capacitor across the feedback resistor, perhaps 100 pF or so, is useful to speed up the transition.

If the signal coming into the +ve input was from a voltage source, then this wouldn't work. However, the input is from an effective resistance of a little below 1 kΩ to a couple of kΩ depending on the position of the potentiometer. That variability will make the size of the hysteresis window dependent on the pot position.

Andy's suggestion of 100 kΩ is a good place to start for the feedback resistor, and will give you a hysteresis of one percent or two of the opamp output swing.

Comment: I can get rid of potentiometer or lock it when I choose specific voltage like 14V (turn of chargin above this value). But I don't it will work. I think that difference between turning off and on relay might be about 1V.

Comment: Will it help when I swap potentiometer output with voltage source ?